# .net can not use my soapServer

Tags: php, .net, wsdl, soapui

I wrote a soapServer in php project.When I soapCall with php everything is Ok.But When another person in .net uses my WSDL , has an error.what's the solution?
I've attached error,WSDL,SoupUi result and functions.Thankful.enter image description here

[Error for .net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr8Ob.png)

[SoapUi error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yczi1.png)

this is panel.wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<definitions
        targetNamespace='urn:server'
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:tns='urn:server'
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">


 <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace='urn:server' xmlns="urn:server">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
            <xsd:complexType name="getActiveServicesResponse">
                <xsd:complexContent>
                    <xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                        <xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:complexContent>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="getHistoryServicesResponse">
                <xsd:complexContent>
                    <xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                        <xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:complexContent>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="getHistoryServicesAllResponse">
                <xsd:complexContent>
                    <xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                        <xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:complexContent>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="getActiveServicesRequest">
        <part name="username" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="mobileNum" type="xsd:string" /></message>
    <message name="getActiveServicesResponse">
        <part name="services" type="tns:getActiveServicesResponse" /></message>
    <message name="unsubscribeRequest">
        <part name="username" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="mobileNum" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="serviceID" type="xsd:string" /></message>
    <message name="unsubscribeResponse">
        <part name="result"  /></message>
    <message name="getHistoryServicesAllRequest">
        <part name="username" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="mobileNum" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="FromDate" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="ToDate" type="xsd:string" /></message>
    <message name="getHistoryServicesAllResponse">
        <part name="history" type="tns:getHistoryServicesAllResponse" /></message>
    <message name="getHistoryServicesRequest">
        <part name="username" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="mobileNum" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="serviceID" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="FromDate" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="ToDate" type="xsd:string" /></message>
    <message name="getHistoryServicesResponse">
        <part name="history" type="tns:getHistoryServicesResponse" /></message>
    <portType name="iPanelPortType">
        <operation name="getActiveServices">
            <input message="tns:getActiveServicesRequest"/>
            <output message="tns:getActiveServicesResponse"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="unsubscribe">
            <input message="tns:unsubscribeRequest"/>
            <output message="tns:unsubscribeResponse"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="getHistoryServicesAll">
            <input message="tns:getHistoryServicesAllRequest"/>
            <output message="tns:getHistoryServicesAllResponse"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="getHistoryServices">
            <input message="tns:getHistoryServicesRequest"/>
            <output message="tns:getHistoryServicesResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="iPanelBinding" type="tns:iPanelPortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="getActiveServices">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:server#getActiveServices" style="rpc"/>
            <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:server" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
            <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:server" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="unsubscribe">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:server#unsubscribe" style="rpc"/>
            <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:server" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
            <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:server" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="getHistoryServicesAll">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:server#getHistoryServicesAll" style="rpc"/>
            <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:server" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
            <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:server" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="getHistoryServices">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:server#getActiveServices" style="rpc"/>
            <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:server" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
            <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:server" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="iPanel">
        <port name="iPanelPort" binding="tns:iPanelBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://37.130.202.161/integratedPanel?wsdl"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

functions

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Exception;
use App\Notification;
use App\LogNotification;
use Log;
class ServiceBinding extends Controller
{

    public function getActiveServices($username,$password,$mobilNum)
    {
return "hello";
    }

    public function unsubscribe($username,$password,$mobilNum,$serviceID)
    {
return "hello";
    }

    public function getHistoryServicesAll($username,$password,$mobilNum,$toDate,$fromDate)
    {
return "hello";
    }

    public function getHistoryServices($username,$password,$mobilNum,$serviceID,$toDate,$fromDate)
    {
return "hello";
    }
}
?>
```

action soap

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Exception;
use Log;

class IntegratedPanelController extends Controller
{

    public function soap() {

        try{
            ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
            ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', '0');

            $server = new \SoapServer('/home/sysadmin/VAS_mci/public/wsdl/panel.wsdl', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
            $server->setClass("App\Http\Controllers\ServiceBinding");
            try {
                $server->handle();
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'IntegratedPanelController.........'. $e->getMessage();
                log::info($e->getMessage());
                $server->fault('Sender', $e->getMessage());
            }
//            echo "SOAP Server started";
        }
        catch (Exception $exception){
            echo 'IntegratedPanelController.........'.$exception->getMessage();
            log::info($exception->getMessage());
            return $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The nice things about standards are that there are so many to choose from. .Net and Java all have different standards when it comes to XML. As XML is flexible it is easy to create a new standard even. One that is incompatible with other standards.

Your WSDL is not WSI compliant thus there is no guarantee it will work in anything outside of your tool kit. WSI is standard for XML and how it is represented in SOAP calls thus if you want your service to work with everything you need to make sure it is WSI complaint.

I ran the WSI compliance test in SOAP UI and it failed. Also you are using RPC type calls which is in some opinions outdated. So we need to make sure our WSDL files are WSI compliant as much as possible to avoid headaches such as this.

A simple example would clarify why we do it. The `null` concept in programming is that null is undefined it has NO VALUE. How do I specify NO VALUE in XML?

Lets assume we have a customer XML which has a name only. How do I specify a NULL Name value? I could do one of the following:

Example 1:

```
<customer>
    <name/>
</customer>
```

Example 2:

```
<customer/>
```

Example 3:

```
<customer>
    <name nullable="true" />
</customer>
```

So as you can see here we have three standards of representing NULL in XML which one is correct? They all are correct in some way. Depends on how you interpret it.

One thing that is very odd is how you have defined your arrays. When I opened your WSDL in liquid XML studio the following lines where invalid:

```
 <xsd:complexType name="getHistoryServicesResponse">
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                    <xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

This generates the following errors:

```
 (15:9) Critical The 'maxOccurs' attribute is not supported in this context.
 (15:9) Critical The 'minOccurs' attribute is not supported in this context.
```

I removed the min and max occurrences and then I hit another error. This contained what the main issue was:

```
Schema Error Undefined complexType 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is used as a base for complex type restriction.
```

Basically the way your are defining your WSDL while valid for PHP is not valid for other languages such as .Net or Java. The problem is in the way you define your arrays.

This question will show you more [Error Consuming a RPC/Encoded SOAP web service in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818426/build-a-xml-rpc-web-service-in-c-sharp). I do realise this is not the answer you are looking for but hopefully it will help you in getting the issue resolved.